# Github Desktop - SSL or HTTPS - but I seem to need BOTH

Tags: github, capistrano, github-for-mac

I have the latest OSX Sierra and am using Capistrano to deploy a WordPress site to staging/prod servers.

I'm also using GitHub Desktop (app) for checking in changes. So the deploy script and the app are both referencing the same .git/config file with this in it:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com/alicam/private-repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

So here's where I get stuck. Github Desktop seems to demand, under remote origin, an HTTPS url, whereas to use Agent Forwarding in the script, I have to use the SSL format (as above).

At the moment, in a very sucky arrangement, I have to edit this file to switch between url formats (HTTPS or SSL) in order to commit a change, then deploy.

UGH!

I've exhausted my search of online docs. Over to you, dear brains trust!

Is it possibly a limitation of the Desktop app? Is there a workaround?

@alicam

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using Capistrano to deploy. Capistrano itself does not use the `.git/config` file at all. It relies on the `:repo_url` setting in your `deploy.rb` file.

So you should be able to leave the HTTPS URL in `.git/config`, and specify an SSH URL in `deploy.rb`. You can then use GitHub Desktop and Capistrano independently without any problems.

```
# deploy.rb
set :repo_url, "git@github.com/alicam/private-repo.git"
```

Comment: Hi Matt. I use Capistrano, but was only saying that for context. The issue is that git at the command line (a composer deploy) requires SSH, in order that agent forwarding works. 

Yet, conversely, Github Desktop (app) required HTTPS. And they're certainly both referencing the same .git/config file.

So I'm still stuck :)

Sorry it mentioning Capistrano was just confusing.